# When are the filing deadlines for the 2020 presidential primaries in each state?

Tags: united-states, primaries

When working on [this answer](https://politics.stackexchange.com/a/47687/1608), I tried to figure out when the filing deadlines were for each state’s presidential primary, and my searches keep turning up contradictory information! [Ballotpedia lists seven states as having deadlines in 2019](https://news.ballotpedia.org/2019/10/24/first-2020-statewide-filing-deadline-is-november-8/), which was referenced by [fivethirtyeight.com](https://fivethirtyeight.com/features/why-deval-patrick-is-making-a-late-bid-for-the-democratic-nomination/), but since [this other list on Ballotpedia](https://ballotpedia.org/State_and_federal_candidate_filing_deadlines_for_2020) lists Iowa’s primary as being in June (it’s the first one, February 3), I have doubts about it.

And then [New Hampshire’s own website](https://sos.nh.gov/nhsos_content.aspx?id=8589987259) seems to indicate its deadline is tomorrow, November 15—and it isn’t on the Ballotpedia list.

Likewise, this [New York Times article](https://www.nytimes.com/2019/11/08/us/politics/2020-primaries-deadlines.html) lists November 26 for California—which I have also seen elsewhere—but it’s also not on Ballotpedia’s list. Going to [California’s own page](https://www.sos.ca.gov/elections/upcoming-elections/presidential-primary-election-march-3-2020/key-dates-deadlines-march-3-2020/) suggests that November 26 is the deadline for “Proof of Generally Advocated for or Recognized Candidate,” but it’s unclear to me what that means. Can a candidate can be included on the ballot during the “Nomination Paper Period for Presidential Candidates not Selected by the Secretary of State,” which ends December 13, if they have not submitted said “Proof” by November 26?

A [PDF on Alabama’s website](https://www.sos.alabama.gov/sites/default/files/voter-pdfs/2020/Presidential-Ballot-Access-Info-2020.pdf) confirms its November 8 deadline, as does [a PDF from Arkansas](https://www.sos.arkansas.gov/uploads/2020_Election_Calendar_7-29-19.pdf) for November 12, so those two, at least, seem to be correct.

Does anyone know where the actual, official, current information can be found? Ideally without having to go to each individual state’s websites (and hope I’m not stumbling upon some outdated page, or misunderstanding what those pages are saying)?

Comment: The Iowa primary is in June.  The Iowa Presidential caucuses are in February.

Comment: @user4556274 Fair enough, but that doesn’t cover the other discrepancies. I fully expect that there are explanations for all of these, but what I really want is to know when things *actually are*, and the differing answers—even if there’s a perfectly good reason why different dates appear—is confusing and, in my opinion, worth addressing.

Answer (score 4):

[Here is a complete list of filing dates with their corresponding state primaries](https://www.thegreenpapers.com/G20/events.phtml?format=chronological&type=ef):

### 2020 Primary and Runoff Elections for Statewide offices and Congress Chronologically with Filing Deadlines

-**Wednesday 6 November 2019** 
     California - Filing Deadline - Primary - in lieu of filing fees
  - **Friday 8 November 2019** 
  Alabama - Filing Deadline with state party - Primary
  - **Tuesday 12 November 2019** 
   Arkansas - Primary/Independent/Third/Minor party
  - **Wednesday 20 November 2019** 
     Maryland - Filing Deadline: Special Election House CD 7.
  - **Monday 2 December 2019** 
     Illinois - Filing Deadline - Primary
Wisconsin - Filing deadline: Special Election CD 7
  - **Friday 6 December 2019** 
   California - Filing Deadline - Primary
  - **Monday 9 December 2019** 
   Texas - Filing Deadline - Primary - Minor Party, Independent intent
  - **Tuesday 10 December 2019** 
    California - Filing dealine Special Election House CD 25 In-Lieu Petitions
  - **Wednesday 11 December 2019** 
   California - Filing Deadline - Primary - if no incumbent files
 - **Wednesday 18 December 2019** 
    Ohio - Filing deadline - Primary
 - **Friday 20 December 2019** 
     North Carolina - Filing Deadline - Primary
 - **Thursday 9 January 2020** 
   California - Filing Deadline: Special Election U.S. House CD 25 Declaration of Candidacy
 - **Friday 10 January 2020** 
  Kentucky - Filing Deadline - Primary
Mississippi - Filing Deadline - Primary/Independent/Third/Minor
 - **Friday 24 January 2020** 
   Maryland - Filing Deadline - Primary
 - **Saturday 25 January 2020** 
    West Virginia - Filing Deadline - Primary
 - **Tuesday 4 February 2020** 
    Maryland - Special Primary House CD 7
New Mexico - Filing Deadline: Preprimary Party Convention
 - **Friday 7 February 2020** 
    Indiana - Filing Deadline - Primary
 - **Tuesday 18 February 2020** 
     Nebraska - Filing Deadline - Primary (Incumbents)
Pennsylvania - Filing Deadline: Primary
Wisconsin - Special General Election House CD 7
 - **Monday 2 March 2020** 
  Nebraska - Filing Deadline - Primary (non-incumbents)
 - **Tuesday 3 March 2020** 
   Alabama - Primary
Alabama - Filing Deadline - Independent/Third/Minor party
Arkansas - Primary
California - Primary and Special Election House CD 25
North Carolina - Primary
North Carolina - Filing Deadline: Independent/Third/Minor
Texas - Primary
 - **Wednesday 4 March 2020** 
     District of Columbia - Filing Deadline - Primary
 - **Friday 6 March 2020** 
     Georgia - Filing Deadline - Primary, Nonpartisan, Independent
 - **Monday 9 March 2020** 
    Montana - Filing Deadline - Primary
 - **Tuesday 10 March 2020** 
    Mississippi - Primary
New Mexico - Filing Deadline: Primary Major Party
Oregon - Filing Deadline - Primary
 - **Friday 13 March 2020** 
    Iowa - Filing Deadline - Primary/Independent/Third/Minor
Idaho - Filing Deadline: Primary/Independent/Third/Minor
Nevada - Filing Deadline - All non-Judicial candidates
 - **Monday 16 March 2020** 
  Maine - Filing Deadline - Primary
 - **Tuesday 17 March 2020** 
  Colorado - Filing Deadline - Primary
Illinois - Primary
New Mexico - Filing Deadline: Primary Write-in
Ohio - Primary
 - **Thursday 19 March 2020** 
    Utah - Filing Deadline - Primary/Independent/Third/Minor
 - **Thursday 26 March 2020** 
  Virginia - Filing Deadline - Primary
 - **Monday 30 March 2020** 
    New Jersey - Filing Deadline - Primary (presumably)
South Carolina - Filing Deadline - Primary
 - **Tuesday 31 March 2020** 
  Alabama - Runoff
Arkansas - Runoff
Missouri - Filing Deadline - Primary
Mississippi - Runoff
South Dakota - Filing Deadline - Primary/Third/Minor
 - **Thursday 2 April 2020** 
  New York - Federal Primary
Tennessee - Filing Deadline - Primary/Independent/Third/Minor
 - **Monday 6 April 2020** 
  Arizona - Filing Deadline - Party/Independent
Colorado - Filing Deadline - Minor Parties
North Dakota - Filing Deadline - Primary
 - **Thursday 9 April 2020** 
    New York - Federal Opportunity to Ballot
 - **Friday 10 April 2020** 
    Oklahoma - Filing Deadline - Primary/Independent/Third/Minor
 - **Tuesday 21 April 2020** 
   Michigan - Filing Deadline - Primary
North Carolina - Second Primary (if run-off is NOT required for a Federal office)
 - **Friday 24 April 2020** 
   Florida - Filing Deadline - Federal offices
 - **Tuesday 28 April 2020** 
    Maryland - Primary and Special Election House CD 7
Pennsylvania - Primary
South Dakota - Filing Deadline - Independent
 - **Tuesday 5 May 2020** 
  Indiana - Primary
Massachusetts - Filing Deadline (nomination papers to the Registrars of Voters for certification) - Primary
 - **Monday 11 May 2020** 
  Texas - Filiing Deadline - Independent President
 - **Tuesday 12 May 2020** 
     California - Special Runoff (if no one receives a majority on 3 March 2020** 
 ) House CD 25
North Carolina - Second Primary (if run-off is required for a Federal office)
Nebraska - Primary
Wisconsin - Special Election House CD 7
West Virginia - Primary
 - **Friday 15 May 2020** 
  Washington - Filing deadline
 - **Tuesday 19 May 2020** 
     Georgia - Primary
Idaho - Primary
Kentucky - Primary
Oregon - Primary
 - **Monday 25 May 2020** 
    Montana - Filing Deadline - Petitions for Independent/Third/Minor
 - **Tuesday 26 May 2020** 
    New York - Filing Deadline - Independent
Texas - Runoff
 - **Thursday 28 May 2020** 
  Vermont - Filing Deadline - Primary
 - **Friday 29 May 2020** 
   Wyoming - Filing Deadline - Primary
 - **Monday 1 June 2020** 
   Alaska - Filing Deadline - Primary
Kansas - Filling Deadline - Primary
Maine - Filing Deadline - Independent
Wisconsin - Filing Deadline: Primary/Independent/Third/Minor
 - **Tuesday 2 June 2020** 
   District of Columbia - Primary
Hawaii - Filing Deadline - Primary/Independent/Third/Minor
Iowa - Primary
Kentucky - Filing Deadline - Independent/Third/Minor
Massachusetts - Filing Deadline (certified papers to the Secretary of the Commonwealth) - Primary
Minnesota - Filing Deadline - Primary/Independent/Third/Minor
Montana - Primary
New Jersey - Primary (presumably)
New Jersey - Filing Deadline - Independent/Third/Minor (presumably)
New Mexico - Primary
South Dakota - Primary
 - **Sunday 7 June 2020** 
   Puerto Rico - Primary (presumably)
 - **Tuesday 9 June 2020** 
   Connecticut - Filing Deadline - Primary
Maine - Primary
North Dakota - Primary
Nevada - Primary
South Carolina - Primary
Virginia - Primary
Virginia - Filing Deadline - Independent/Third/Minor
 - **Friday 12 June 2020** 
   New Hampshire - Filing Deadline for Candidacy/Intent - Primary/Independent/Third/Minor
 - **Monday 22 June 2020** 
   Illinois - Filing Deadliine - Independent/Third/Minor
 - **Tuesday 23 June 2020** 
   New York - Primary
South Carolina - Runoff
 - **Wednesday 24 June 2020** 
     Rhode Island - Filing Deadline - Declarations of Candidacy (presumably)
 - **Thursday 25 June 2020** 
    New Mexico - Filing Deadline: Minor/Independent/Independent President/Write-in General Election
 - **Tuesday 30 June 2020** 
     Colorado - Primary
Florida - Filing deadline: Write-in candidates for President and Vice President
Indiana - Filing Deadline - Independent/Third/Minor
Oklahoma - Primary
Utah - Primary
July 2020** 
    Rhode Island - Filing Deadline - Submit nomination papers (presumably)
 - **Thursday 9 July 2020** 
  Colorado - Filing Deadline - Unaffiliated candidate nomination petition
 - **Tuesday 14 July 2020** 
     Delaware - Filing Deadline - Primary
Georgia - Filing Deadline - Independent/Third/Minor Petitions (including President)
 - **Thursday 16 July 2020** 
    Michigan - Filing Deadline - Independent (No Party Affiliation 168.590c)
 - **Friday 17 July 2020** 
     Louisiana - Filing Deadline - Primary/Independent/Third/Minor
 - **Tuesday 21 July 2020** 
   Georgia - Primary Runoff
North Carolina - Filing deadline: Write-in submitted to County
 - **Wednesday 29 July 2020** 
    Massachusetts - Filing Deadline (nomination papers to the Registrars of Voters for certification) - Independent/Third/Minor
 - **Friday 31 July 2020** 
  West Virginia - Filing Deadline - Independent/Third/Minor
 - **Saturday 1 August 2020** 
     Virgin Islands - Primary Election (presumably)
 - **Monday 3 August 2020** 
  Kansas - Filling Deadline - Independent/Third/Minor.
Maryland - Filing Deadline - Independent/Third/Minor.
Pennsylvania - Filing Deadline - Independent/Third/Minor
 - **Tuesday 4 August 2020** 
  Arizona - Primary and Special Election Senate Class 3
Kansas - Primary
Michigan - Primary
Michigan - Nomination Deadline - Third/Minor party (168.686a)
Missouri - Primary
South Dakota - Filing deadline - Independent Presidential Candidates
Washington - Primary
 - **Wednesday 5 August 2020** 
   Connecticut - Filing Deadline - New Party/No Party
District of Columbia - Filing Deadline - Independent/Third/Minor
North Carolina - Filing deadline: Write-in submitted to State
New Hampshire - Candidates submit nomination papers to local Supervisors - Independent/Third/Minor
 - **Thursday 6 August 2020** 
     Tennessee - Primary
Vermont - Filing Deadliine - Independent/Third/Minor
 - **Friday 7 August 2020** 
     California - Filing Deading - Independent Presidential
 - **Saturday 8 August 2020** 
    Hawaii - Primary
 - **Tuesday 11 August 2020** 
  Connecticut - Primary
Minnesota - Primary
South Dakota - Secondary Election (runoff)
Vermont - Primary
Wisconsin - Primary
 - **Friday 14 August 2020** 
     Iowa - Filing Deadline - President
 - **Monday 17 August 2020** 
     South Carolina - Filing Deadline - Nonpartisan
Utah - Filing Deadline - Unaffiliated President
Vermont - Filing Deadline - Party Committee (in lieu of primary)
Wyoming - Filing Deadline: Minor Party
 - **Tuesday 18 August 2020** 
   Alaska - Primary
Florida - Primary
Missouri - Filing Deadline - Independent/Third/Minor
Wyoming - Primary
 - **Thursday 20 August 2020** 
   Alaska - Filing Deadline - Independent
Tennessee - Filing Deadline - Independent Presidential Candidates
 - **Monday 24 August 2020** 
    Massachusetts - Filing Deadline (certified papers to the Secretary of the Commonwealth) - Independent/Third/Minor
 - **Tuesday 25 August 2020** 
     Idaho - Filing Deadline - President - Independent
Oklahoma - Runoff
Oregon - Filing Deadline - Independent/Third/Minor
Wyoming - Filing Deadline - Independent
 - **Saturday 29 August 2020** 
  Guam - Primary Election
 - **Monday 31 August 2020** 
    North Dakota - Filing Deadline - Independent/Third/Minor.
 - **Tuesday 1 September 2020** 
   Delaware - Filing Deadline - Independent
Nebraska - Filing Deadline - Independent/Third/Minor
 - **Wednesday 2 September 2020** 
  New Hampshire - Filing Deadline for Nomination Papers - Independent/Third/Minor
 - **Friday 4 September 2020** 
  Hawaii - Filing Deadline: Presidential nominee
Mississippi - Filing Deadline - Independent Candidates for President
 - **Tuesday 8 September 2020** 
  New Hampshire - Primary
Rhode Island - Primary
 - **Tuesday 15 September 2020** 
  Delaware - Primary
Massachusetts - Primary
 - **Tuesday 3 November 2020** 
    Alaska - General Election
Alabama - General Election
Arkansas - General Election
American Samoa - General Election (presumably)
Arizona - General Election and Special Election Senate Class 3
California - General Election
Colorado - General Election
Connecticut - General Election
District of Columbia - General Election
Delaware - General Election
Florida - General Election
Georgia - General Election and tentative Special Election Senate Class 3
Guam - General Election
Hawaii - General Election
Iowa - General Election
Idaho - General Election
Illinois - General Election
Indiana - General Election
Kansas - General Election
Kentucky - General Election
Louisiana - General Election - Open Primary / Presidential / Congressional
Massachusetts - General Election
Maryland - General Election
Maine - General Election
Michigan - General Election
Minnesota - General Election
Missouri - General Election
Northern Marianas - General Election (presumably)
Mississippi - General Election
Montana - General Election
North Carolina - General Election
North Dakota - General Election
Nebraska - General Election
New Hampshire - General Election
New Jersey - General Election (presumably)
New Mexico - General Election
Nevada - General Election
New York - General Election
Ohio - General Election
Oklahoma - General Election
Oregon - General Election
Pennsylvania - General Election
Puerto Rico - General Election
Rhode Island - General Election
South Carolina - General Election
South Dakota - General Election
Tennessee - General Election
Texas - General Election
Utah - General Election
Virginia - General Election
Virgin Islands - General Election (presumably)
Vermont - General Election
Washington - General Election
Wisconsin - General Election
West Virginia - General Election
Wyoming - General Election
 - **Tuesday 17 November 2020** 
  Guam - General Election Runoff (if necessary) (presumably)
Virgin Islands - Gubernatorial Runoff Election (presumably)
 - **Tuesday 1 December 2020** 
    Georgia - State and Local General Runoff
 - **Saturday 5 December 2020** 
    Louisiana - Runoff Election - Open General / Congressional
 - **Tuesday 5 January 2021** Georgia - Federal General Runoff and tentative Special Runoff Election Senate Class 3